# Is SilkTest a good Automation tool like Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, silktest

I have 3 + years experience in Selenium Automation. Now i got an opportunity in a company to work in SilkTest Automation tool. Is it good to learn SilkTest? Is it really worth to learn and can it be used in Continous Integration testing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

SilkTest like most expensive commercial testing packages is used mainly in large corporate companies. If this is where you want to grow then sure it is fine to learn it.

I think test automation skills transfer between frameworks and tools. The fundamentals are the same.

If you have a hard time learning new tools then maybe I would not switch as SilkTest will not be in large demand. Meaning you might need to learn a new tool as you switch jobs in the future.

Running SilkTests on Jenkins (CI): http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/f/forum/5176/how-to-integrate-silktest-with-jenkins

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to consider is Silk is a harder platform to work with as it does not have nearly the community support that WebDriver does. i.e. if you are stuck on something in WebDriver, chances are you can simply google the answer. Not so with Silk.

The only way I would do it, is if a company I was working for was stable, and  an established user of Silk Test, as this would give you a niche thats hard to replace.

It probably can be used in CI, if nothing else, Jenkins can do things with SSH, but again its a question of community support.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for suggestion. I need to check on support given to company.

Comment: I have actually used their support (years ago), and it was quite good, but it will never be as good as google and stack overflow